# How does one see what data is stored in the RDS database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Running our app on Amazon RDS. How does one review / inspect data in the database? For example, how can I get a list of `articles`?

My app is running on Ruby on Rails and on Heroku. One method I thought of, is by running the Heroku console command.

Is there a better way to see what data is stored in the RDS database?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) to view data, run queries, and so on. It connects right up to the Amazon RDS MySQL instance using the regular MySQL settings.

**Updated:**

Be sure to add the ip address of the computer for which you're connecting to the RDS instance to the access list in RDS. IIRC, by default RDS instances will only accept connections from within AWS.

Comment: Hmm, I am using Sequel Pro. Wondering what you provide for the host section?

Comment: I used the "Endpoint" `<instancename>....rds.amazonaws.com` fqdn in Workbench and it worked fine. You can find it in the instance information for your RDS instance.  I believe MySQL Workbench is available on OS X as well, but if you've found something you like, there's no need to switch. I've not used Sequel Pro, but it looks nice.

Comment: Hmm, can't seem to get this to work with Sequel Pro. It doesn't seem to connect. In the "host" section, I have: http://app_name.mckawjk4obe2.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com. Is this what you have?

Comment: Yes, something similar to that. See the update to my answer for another possible solution.

Comment: Does this work if you specify that the RDS instance is not publicly accessible?

Comment: I answered this a LONG time ago, but IIRC this does work on an instance that's not publicly available as long as you add your machine's info into the access list for the RDS.

Answer (score -1):

I was using SequelPro but they don't support ssl. Amazon RDS says something to the effect of having to use SSH to connect your EC2 to your RDS.

This is essentially what was done in the following tutorial which uses MySQL Workbench: http://thoughtsandideas.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/monitoring-and-managing-amazon-rds-databases-using-mysql-workbench/

I had also been using SequelPro before but this tutorial is very clear and I was up and running on MySQL Workbench in just a few minutes.